# Signal QWebPage::loadFinished(bool) returns twice?

Tags: qt4, webkit, signals-slots, qwebkit

I got a problem with QWebPage::loadFinished (bool) signal , it calls back twice , is that normal ? ( there's no link following at all , e.g HTTP status 302 )

Consider the following code , the whole thing may cause problem , is trying to load another link within that slot , will this be a problem ?

If i do a `qDebug() << thisUrl;` each time in `loadFinished(bool)` slot , i could see it for 3 times , is that normal , one for url `XXX` , and two for url `YYY` , and the last two links are exactly the same.

```
class Dummy
{
    public:
        Dummy() 
        { 
            page = new QWebPage(this);  
            connect (page , SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)) , SLOT(loadFinished(bool)));
            page->mainFrame()->load ("XXX");
        }

    private:
        QWebPage *page;

    private slots:
        void loadFinished (bool ok)
        {
            if ( ! ok ) return;

            const QString & thisUrl = page->mainFrame()->url().toString();

            if ( thisUrl matches XXX )
            {
                // parse reply message of url XXX
                page->mainFrame()->load ("YYY");
                return;
            }

            if ( thisUrl matches YYY )
            {
                // parse reply message of url YYY
                return;
            }
        }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

im seeing this too with qt 4.7.4 (with phantomjs). i used the frame's loadFinished instead of the page's and it isn't sent twice.

Comment: i dont really know and i dont really have the inclination to go inside the Qt code to find out why. maybe you could file a bug report?